# Trying to split a complex shapefile by Australian states

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector

I'm trying to work with a 1:1 million scale shapefile of the geology of Australia.

When the whole lot is loaded in to QGIS (over 200,000 polygons) it will freeze and go to slow to work with.

Ideally I would split the data by each state and just turn on which state I need at a time and that will hopefully run full speed.

However I can't figure out how to split the shapefile properly (700mb file),  I've tried a vector layer split and clip in the geoprocessing tools but I can't get them to work properly. The clip tool just generates a blank shapefile (I tried drawing a polygon shape as a vector file as the output layer so maybe that part was wrong).

Comment: Perhaps the spatial references don't match. I would intersect the states of Australia and the geology then you can use a definition query (like state = 'Tasmania') to trim the data. Yes it will take a while to run, but will be worth it in the end. Also, OGR2OGR can be used with clipping if you don't mind command line and it is very fast.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried using the intersect tool with a polygon drawn over the geology layer, both those layers active. However it does not work right, both layers have the same CRS specified. The resultant shapefile is only 1kb, im not sure why it doesnt seem to be grabbing any data from the layer

Comment: I have found OGR2OGR (http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html) most helpful, if you're comfortable with command/DOS, use -clipsrclayer <States_shapefile> -clipsrcwhere "State = 'Tasmania'" to extract just Tasmania from the input. You can do it in a batch file for each state.

Comment: Would it be a possibility to just set the "Scale dependent visibility" for the layer to something like 1:200.000?

Comment: BTW is this dataset public / free.

Comment: its geoscience australia public data. I managed to get it working without the use of OGR , the intersect tool worked once i used a proper states shapefile grid to intersect the geology. Takes probably 4 hours per state but once its done its done. Each state pans and zooms full speed on a slow computer now.